# Wine and system audio mute one another

Tags: wine, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm running into an awkward problem. Here's the thing:

If I start up my computer and run a Wine instance (Guild Wars 2, in this case, though it doesn't and shouldn't matter), sound works fine. While the sound works, the application does not show up under the "sound" tab in settings. And any other application launched thereafter will not have sound until the Wine instance is closed. I'm assuming Wine runs ALSA.

If I start any other application that requires sound before running Guild Wars 2, Guild Wars 2 will not have any sound. All the other applications appear to run pulseaudio.

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: How is Wine's audio output configured? (It should use PA but appears to use ALSA directly.)

Comment: Not sure how I check this, but this is what Wine configuration says under the "Audio" tab: "Selected driver: winealsa.drv". Under Defaults, all default audio devices are selected. "Test sound" works like it should, and will actually sound whilst any other application also emits sound.

Comment: And what device is Wine's default device?

Comment: Out: HDA ATI SB - ALC887-VD Analog. Which also shows up in alsamixer. Pulseaudio only shows "Built-in Audio Analog Surround 5.1", but this is not an option in wine.